# Spring Data JPA ignores FetchMode

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm having 2 entities. First one is

```
public class TechnicalDataItem {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ItemLabelId id;
```

Id class is:

```
public class ItemLabelId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TECHNICAL_LABEL_ID")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private TechnicalLabel technicalLabel;
```

with @ManyToOne relation to

```
public class TechnicalLabel {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    private String name;

    @Basic
    private String value;
```

When I try to load all data from TechnicaDataItem by calling

```
technicalDataItemRepository.findAll()
```

I got a bunch of selects, and the load is slow. Shouldn't there be the join and only one select? Am I missing something?

technicalDataRepository is JpaRepository.

Comment: Spring Data JPA has nothing to do with that, it is just how JPA reacts to your setup. I would suspect that doing a query with the `EntityManager` yields the same results. Which JPA version are you using, I believe JPA 2.0 allows only for primitives in the embedded id.

Comment: spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 1.1.9

Comment: That still doesn't state which JPA version. As stated it has nothing to do with Spring Data JPA but how JPA reacts on your annotations. Without Spring Data JPA you would get the same issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the relationship definition you are running into N+1 query problem. JPA by default will execute multiple selects to pull the child relation items.

You have one select for the `TechnicalDataItem`, and then N additional selects for `TechnicalLabel`.

To circumvent additional N queries, use `join fetch` on `findAll` method of `technicalDataItemRepository`.

Here is an example of the same.

```
@Query("Select tdi from TechnicalDataItem tdi join fetch tdi.technicalLabel")
List<TechnicalDataItem> findAll();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: well that was my idea but I cant go directly with join fetch tdi.technicalLabel, i need to go with join fetch tdi.id.technicalLabel, and it acts same :( a lot of selects... Could that be something with this @EmbededId?

Comment: Do you have ```@Embeddable``` on ```ItemLabelId```? Also ```technicalLabel``` should not be inside the ```ItemLabelId``` from organization of entity perspective. Id should only contain id and nothing else.

Comment: Yes I have, and it is composite id, so that's why it is inside the ItemLabeId

Comment: You think I should put only labelId there and to manulay load label when I need it?

Comment: For composite keys, I have always used native columns not the complex entities. You can try taking it out and see how it behaves.

Comment: That was the problem... When I changed it to the id only, it was ok... Thanks!